# how to initialize a observable using typescript with rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs

When there is no value, how to initialize a `observable` value? either i am not set empty value as well.

code :

```
 interface PropsProduct {
    id: number,
    picture: string,
    price: number,
    name: string,
    combo: boolean,
    discount: number
}

 myArray: Observable<PropsProduct>
  
  constructor(private readonly dataService: DataService) {
    this.myArray = [] //throws the error;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: a simple google search would have landed you [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation), and it has everything you need

Comment: It depends. What is responsible for emitting values for that observable? What depends on that observable? Is that observable simply being used to hold the state of your component? Will there be persistent observers looking for updates to that observable? How do you intend to use it?

Comment: @JeffMercado - just I need to initialize to avoid error. until the new value arrive let it be a empty array

Comment: New value from what? Where does it come from? the service or some other source? If you want to make and observe changes, you'll probably want a subject of some kind (e.g., BehaviorSubject).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [of](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) to initiate observable

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

this.myArray = of([]);
```